# Cannot call method 'on' of undefined (duplicated devices)

Tags: coffeescript

Im getting the cannot call method 'on' of undefined.

When using singel devices no error. But cant see where it goes wrong.

```
 _temperature: null
    _temperature1: null

    attributes:
      Temperature:
        description: "Boiler Water Temperature"
        type: "number"
        unit: '°C'
        acronym: 'G'
      Temperature1:
        description: "Room Temperature"
        type: "number"
        unit: '°C'
        acronym: 'T'

    constructor: (@config, lastState) ->
      @id = @config.id
      @name = @config.name
      @_temperature = lastState?.temperature?.value
      @_temperature1 = lastState?.temperature1?.value
      super()

      plugin.otgw.on("boiler_water_temperature", (data) =>
        if data?
          @_temperature = Number(data)
          @emit 'temperature', @_temperature
      )
     plugin.otgw.on("room_temperature", (data) =>
        if data?
          @_temperature1 = Number(data)
          @emit 'temperature1', @_temperature1
      )

    getTemperature: -> Promise.resolve(@_temperature)
    getTemperature1: -> Promise.resolve(@_temperature1)

  return plugin
```

Comment: So you fixed both indentation issues, right? What is `plugin.otgw` and why would it raise a `"room_temperature"` event?

Comment: No not yet.. stil strugling. The orginal code this i compiled is working but based upon 1 device. i tried to combine the devices in 1 script. the "room_temperature" is captured from a different file as well as "boiler_temperature".

Comment: Please fix the whitespace issues above. Please don't use capitalized names, except for classes. Although you might mimic testdata. `Constructor` is a reserved keyword in coffeescript, please don't use it outside a class. Although you seem to want to define a class, but you are missing the class keywork and the structure doesn't fit: http://coffeescript.org/#classes . Is there a line missing?
Where do you import / init plugin? Why do you wrap plugin in  a class and the return it 'naked'?

Answer (score 0):

Just found a whitespace causing the error. However the data is still not begin captured from the temperature1.